# Pass info to another native android App

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I send information from application **A** to application **B** (written in Java) with values of type **Int** all ok, but my **string** values: *Username* and *Password* in application B is always null.

**Code Application A:**

```
public void MakeReport(int jobId, int jobType)
        {
            var intent = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(AppBundle);
            if (intent is null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();

            // Set Data
            intent.PutExtra(UsernameMessage, javaUsername);
            intent.PutExtra(PasswordMessage, javaPassword);
            intent.PutExtra(JobIdMessage, jobId);
            intent.PutExtra(JobTypeMessage, jobType);

// Test All OK
            string usernameTest = intent.GetStringExtra("USER_NAME_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE");
            string passwordTest = intent.GetStringExtra("USER_PASSWORD_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE");
            int jobIdTest = intent.GetIntExtra("JOB_ID_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE", -1);
            int jobTypeTest = intent.GetIntExtra("JOB_TYPE_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE", 0);

            Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }

        #endregion
```

**Code Application B:**

```
@Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  initLoginPopup();
  String login = intent.getStringExtra("USER_NAME_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE");
  String password = intent.getStringExtra("USER_PASSWORD_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE");
  int jobType =  intent.getIntExtra("JOB_TYPE_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE", 0);
  int jobId = intent.getIntExtra("JOB_ID_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE", 0);
  loginFromMdoSchedule(login, password, jobType, jobId).start();
 }

E/EXTRAS: [JOB_ID_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE=0]
                   [USER_NAME_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE=null]
                   [USER_PASSWORD_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE=null]
                   [JOB_TYPE_FROM_MDO_SCHEDULE=2]
E/END@@@@: Dumping Intent end
```

Comment: In app B, check that in manifest the activity has android:exported="true"

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for my colleague to check it out. He develops application B

Comment: Are you using DepencyService to startActivity? Can you show the Application B's  Activity's manifest?  I have tested many times, every time, I will get the data in Application B. Or can you provide the demo on github?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Hi, i also tested many times and get data, but when my collegue debug it on app B he does not receive a password and login. Unfortunately I can not provide a demo, but yes I use DependencyService, and I'll throw out the code from Activities on Google in zip archive:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZaKssG_jJjOZ4_Y3Z6UttBacaoeKpHfp

Comment: Hi, in application B, are your starting the MainActivity or otherActivity? From your question, your colleague has got the intent, but can't take the string? BTW, `Forms.Context` is obsolete. And he use `onNewIntent` to receive the intent, so his activity must be started before your app.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I do not know about the application B, but I can assume that this is LoginActivity, because the second application is launched from it.

Yea, i changed Froms.Context to CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(intent);

Comment: Try to start an activity in your app with the same method and see the data, if you can get it, that's  not your problem.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Ok, thanks for the help.